# Quotas on individual sites

Tags: powershell, quota

Is there any way to apply storage quotas to individual sites, rather than the entire site collection?

Comment: Can you add the tag Powershell to this thread for others to find?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't possible.  You can always break out your site into it's own site collection and using managed paths it can "look" like it's a subsite.

For example:  Your main site collection might be http://intranet/usa/ and your subsite may have the url http://intranet/usa/subsite/.  You can then create a explicit managed path to usa/subsite and create a new site collection there.

Now the url is the same but you'll need to take care of the navigation.  At http://intranet/usa/ you just modify the top nav to point to the subsite site collection.  At the subsite site collection, modify the portal url to be the parent site collection, /usa/, or come up with your own breadcrumb site map provider to do this for you.

Comment: The problem is that it then separates the navigation between the site collections; we need the sites that a user can access to appear in the quick launch bars and if we create a new collection these no longer update automatically.

Comment: Right, that's why I was saying you can create your own site map providers that display the quicklaunch, breadcrumbs, and/or top nav exactly how you want.  We have our environment setup similar to how I explained above and with my custom site map providers, end users don't really know they are going to a different site collection.

Answer (score -1):

To enhance Steve's answer, there isn't a normal (or easy) way to do this as applying quotas is done at a Site Collection level.

But you can use either C#.NET or Powershell on one of your servers to load the SharePoint assembly's, get ahold of the site using SPWeb, then walk into the sites normally-hidden properties to update it to one of the quota's that is different than the rest of the Site Collection.

I have done this for both standard sites and MySites.  I'll post the solution for this tonight.

---

On a SharePoint server where you have Powershell 1 or 2 installed, create a file called 'SharePoint_Site_UpdateQuota.ps1' and place the following code inside it.

## .\SharePoint_Site_UpdateQuota.ps1 "http://server_url:30002/" "personal/jsmith/" "Personal Site Higher Limit"

param(
    [string] $rqurdstrPath = $(Throw "--SharePoint Core Path required."), #required parameter
    [string] $rqurdstrPashSubweb = $(Throw "--SharePoint Path Subweb required."), #required parameter
    [string] $rqurdstrQuotaTemplateName = $(Throw "--SharePoint Quota Template Name required.") #required parameter
)

Write-Host "Beginning Processing--`n"

#Before#
## stsadm -o enumsites -url "http://server_url:30002/"
    #

#After#
## stsadm -o enumsites -url "http://server_url:30002/"
    #

## Global Variables ##
$strDebug = "True" #"True" "False"

$strHomeDir="O:\Powershell"
$str12Hive="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN\"

Write-Host "strHomeDir: $strHomeDir"
Write-Host "rqurdstrPath: $rqurdstrPath"
Write-Host "rqurdstrPashSubweb: $rqurdstrPashSubweb"
Write-Host "rqurdstrQuotaTemplateName: $rqurdstrQuotaTemplateName"

## Activating ##
Write-Host "`nActivating--`n"
cd $strHomeDir

## Do Work ##
# Load SharePoint assembly #
$SPFarm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local #$SPFarm #$SPFarm.Services | Where {$_ -like "*SPWebService*"}
$SPFarmSPWebService = $SPFarm.Services | Where {$_ -like "*SPWebService*" -and $_ -notlike "*WSS_Admin*"}

Write-Host "**SPFarmSPWebService"
#$SPFarmSPWebService #$SPFarmSPWebService.QuotaTemplates

$quota = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPQuotaTemplate #.default
$quotaColl = $SPFarmSPWebService.QuotaTemplates

Write-Host "**quotaColl" #$quotaColl.count
$site = ""
$subWeb = ""
$strAllowUpdate = "False"

foreach ($quotaInd in $quotaColl) {
    $strQuotaIndName = [string]$quotaInd.Name
    if($strQuotaIndName -eq $rqurdstrQuotaTemplateName) {
     Write-Host "-$strQuotaIndName- found"
     $quota = $quotaInd
     $strAllowUpdate = "True"
     break
    }
}

$strPathMySites = $rqurdstrPath + $rqurdstrPashSubweb
write-host "strPathMySites: $strPathMySites"
if($rqurdstrPath -like "*:30002*") {
    #For MySites
    $site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($strPathMySites)
}
else {
    #For normal Sites
    $site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($rqurdstrPath) #$site.AllWebs
    $subWeb = $site.OpenWeb($rqurdstrPashSubweb)
    write-host "subWeb: $subWeb"
}

write-host "site: $site"
write-host "quota: $quota"

Write-Host "`n`nAllow Update: $strAllowUpdate"
$site.Quota
if($strAllowUpdate -eq "True") {
    $site.Quota = $quota
    $site.Quota
}

#For MySites
if($rqurdstrPath -notlike "*:30002*") {
    $subWeb.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()

## End Processing ##
Write-Host "`nEnd Processing--`n"

trap [Exception] { 
      write-host $("`tTRAPPED: " + $_.Exception.GetType().FullName)<br>
      write-host $("`tTRAPPED: " + $_.Exception.Message) 
      break
}

Comment: Interesting... I'd like to see that solution.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see in your code where you are updating the subsite, only the spsite object which is the site collection.

Comment: Aye, this doesn't work. Attemping to modify the quota for a subsite just changes the quota for the entire site collection it's a member of.