# Provision SharePoint Site using Data stored in List via Powershell

Tags: list, powershell, provisioning

I have a custom list where users submit there request for new site, which stores, information such as Site Name, Site url, template type, Size of the site, Site Owners etc.

Can I use powershell script to capture that data and provision sites based off that?

If that can be done, can you please lead me to the right direction on where to start? I am a novice Powershell User and SharePoint Administrator.

Comment: How does a user know the size of the site before a site is provisioned?  Is this custom list only used for requesting new sites, or does it also satisfy some other business requirement?

Comment: We have Quota template set up for the sites for diffrent site types in central admin. I have a Choice Column Set up for users to select three diffrent sizes in the list, which tallies up with the quota size i have available.

Comment: I don't think you can enforce a disk quota on a website (`SPWeb`) as it's a setting you set on a site collection (`SPSite`).  Please look [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/644/quotas-on-individual-sites) as a reference.

Comment: We have been doing that for some time now using central admin site creation page. Question is can this be done using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

To read the items from list :

```
$sourceWebURL = "http://sharepointsite"
$sourceListName = "mylist"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.GetItems()

$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_['ID']
    Write-Host $_['Title']
}
```

To create Site with:

```
New-SPWeb http://somesite/subweb1 -Template "STS#0"
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607579(v=office.15).aspx

http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=340

Comment: `$_["Column Name"]` will work for a lot of the fields, but some (like Choice or User or Group) fields will require a little more.  [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx)'s a link to help out with that.

Comment: can i pass $sourceWebURL  inside -url property of New-Spweb -url $sourceWebURL  as such

Comment: Yes you can use variables.